# Table with alternate colors and tr rounded corners

Tags: css, html-table, alternate

I need to create a table that has both alternate and rounded TR corners, managed to create the tr corners using something like this http://jsfiddle.net/tXa53/

but now I cannot create the alternate part is there a jQuery script or something that will work?

Comment: if you want a working solution for <IE9 then you must set alternating classes in the <tr>s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working only with css:

http://jsfiddle.net/tXa53/3/

I just added:

```
.newHardware tr:nth-of-type(2n) td{
     background:#777;
}
```

you could as well use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type(even|odd)`

Comment: @Dipaks 1) i said working css - you can't solve it in other ways without adding classes 2) i didnt use nth-child - it was the OP 3) i know about browser compatibility 4) since the OP used nth-child i assumed css3-selectors are okay

Comment: it don't needs to work in IE8, he has made his rounded corners with css3 and no js fallback, so IE8 can't be a concern for him